# Is 'I want it back' a raising construction?

Tags: raising

> *I want it back.*

Semantically, *it* is not the direct object of the verb *want* but syntactically *it* is.

Then, is this a raising construction even though it doesn't have any subordinate clause?

Comment: Why do you think *it* is not a direct object -- removing *back* doesn't change the semantics anymore than removing *again* in "I want it again".

Comment: @amI Well, maybe you're right. But that's just coincidental, I think. How about this example then? _I want it back to how it used to be._ Is _it_ still a direct object? And I even think that _I want it back_ can mean _I want it back to how it used to be_ in appropriate context.

Comment: If you think that eliding 'to be' is permitted in raising-to-object, then yes, "I want it [to be] back" would qualify (but 'back' cannot be a verb here, as in "I saw him back into the mailbox") -- and your 'back' could just as well be called an object complement.

Comment: @amI But _I want it back_ does not mean "I want it to be back" when you're asking someone to return _it_. Regarding calling it an object complement, are you saying that _She made me upset_ is a raising construction?

Comment: No to the last -- "She made me upset the jar" is raising, but "She made me upset" is object complement (although the differing terms are due to separate approaches -- the deep destinations are not so different).  When you ask for something back, you are indeed merely stating that you want it *to be* back.  That you are asking for it to be returned by someone is just how reality works, when you don't expect it *to come* back on its own.

Comment: For me *it* is not a direct object - compare *I want him dead*, where what wanted is clealy not *him*, but the state of affairs expressed by *him dead*. In that respect it is a bit like a raising construction, but I don't see why *him* / *it* logically has to appear twice, or why we'd want to call a construction without a subordinate verb a raising construction. It's just a pattern of complementation licensed by *want*.

Comment: Of course it is elided, compare German "Ich will es zurück [haben]" (I want [to have] it back) and variants, where the elision is overt. Whether that still counts as raising I don't know, but wikipedia's object-raising examples like "Fred wants **us** to help" do not have word for word translation. On the other hand, similar cases like "Ich will es zurück bringen" (I want to return it) are not elided, so you might have a point.

Comment: @vectory I'm not sure it's elided but don't know of a reliable test. I can't comment on your German example but how does it show that the En construction involves elision? If there is elision, it only seems to be possible when the element only appears once in the logical structure - *she wants me (to be) there* can/does mean [she wants (me be there)] and elision is possible (if it really is elision and not a different syntactic structure), whereas *she wants me to go there* can only mean [she wants me (me go there)] and elision is not possible.

Comment: @Minty "I can't comment on your German example but how does it show that the En construction involves elision?" -- erm, only because I say so judging from my native intuition, so I might well be wrong. Thinking a little further about this, since I commented on various other matters about "to", recently, it may be that the proto-typical sentence is just prepositional, "she calls me to ...", which then changed a lot; i.e. how do you parse "call to help"? The German variant uses the noun "zu Hilfe rufen", not the verb "helfen". Am not sure about the history. ...

Comment: ... So intrinsically we hear *I want it to me*, if "to" proto-typically requires a place. Thus "back" is a pronoun, like "I gave it to her"? Imagine a lot of handwaving and compare "Ich gab es Ihr" (no "zu" in sight, "Ihr" being 3. p. sg. accusative) but variably "Ich sagte [zu] Ihr".

Comment: I didn't mean to say that the claim of elision negatrs the claim of different syntax. Rather, the elision works despite slightly changed syntax of the object phrase ("OP" is a thing I hope).

Comment: The marked subordinate clause might be rather "come back", cp "zurück bekommen", "bekommen" (receive), false friend of "become", where "bekommen" also may imply a state change, similar to colloquial "to get", e.g. "Es bekommt Angst" (it becomes affraid - it gets fear) and quite idiomatic "Er bekam es mit der Angst zu tun" (he became/got it with the fear to do?). However, we should only count what a native speaker learns. Do they see object-raising at all, and specifically in "I want it back"? Rather not, if it's trivially compared to "I want it now".

Comment: I don't think *I want it back* and *I want it now* have the same syntax, but staying with the first case, if there's elision of *have* then the *back* modifies the elided verb rather than being directly predicated of *it* - but then we would find adverbs and not adjectives in sentences like *I want bars 32 to 40 slower*. I think there are other problems with *have*. For me, if there's an elided verb it's *to be*, but I'm not sure what grounds there are for saying that the predicative relationship between *bars 32 to 40* and *slower* is down to an elided *be*, rather than saying that *want*...

Comment: ...can take a complement that is inherently predicative. Sometimes adding *to be* changes the meaning slightly. For example, if speaking to a decorator *I want that wall red* is fine but *I want that wall to be red* sounds a bit off, as though you are expecting it to magically turn red or wishing that it were red, rather than telling him to bring about a situation such that *red* can validly be predicated of *that wall*. That could be down to pragmatics, but I would link it with whether *that wall* appears twice in the logical structure, as it would in a raising construction:

Comment: *I want it to be red* CAN mean I want it (it is red), with *it* in an agentive role which it can't play (hence the strangeness), whereas *I want it red* can only really be understood as I want (it is red), in which *it* has only one role, as part of the predicative complement of *want*. This could still be pragmatics though - I still don't know of a reliable test and in the end the reasons I don't believe there is an elided *to be* is firstly that it is simpler just to say that the pattern of complementation is inherently predicative, rather than positing a predicating verb, and secondly...